# How can I make a bootable usb flashdrive?

Tags: linux, dd

Can I just dd an Ubuntu 11.04 mini.iso to an usb flashdrive an boot from it? or what am I missing?

Comment: You want a liveUSB, or a rescue USB, or just an alternate boot medium for you system?

Comment: an installer, from where i can install ubuntu, the same as i burn the mini.iso to cd & boot from it

Comment: there are easy and details instructions on the Ubuntu site on how to make bootable USB sticks. Please put some effort into answering your own questions by looking at documentation. The expertise on this site is better reserved for solving problems that don't already have obvious answers.

Comment: Some distributions make their ISO [hybrid](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/Doc/isolinux#HYBRID_CD-ROM.2FHARD_DISK_MODE) so it can be `dd`ed onto a USB and the USB will boot. Gentoo is [one example](http://www.gentoo.org/news/20110308-livedvd.xml). AFAIK Ubuntu doesn't provide this.

Comment: FYI, you should be using the normal desktop iso to install rather than the mini, unless you are stuck with an ancient < 512 mb flash drive.  That way the installer doesn't have to download everything from the interwebs, plus you get a live environment you can test and repair with.

Comment: @Caleb - With regards to "The expertise on this site is better reserved for solving problems that don't already have obvious answers.", I believe Joel's said on the podcast that duplicating questions answered elsewhere *is* applicable on SE sites.  So this does sound like a valid question.

Comment: @JohnMacIntyre: Joel's recent comment in a podcast specifically mentioned two types of questions. Those with definitive canonical answers elsewhere and those found on some random forum that need some peer review to be useful. In this case the most up to date complete information is going to be provided by Canonical in their very clear instructions. There is little to nothing we can add that is valuable beyond their simple and detailed instructions. This is equivalent to Joel's example of Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to `dd if=linux.iso of=/dev/sdx`, where x is the letter for your USB device. Don't use `/dev/sdx1`, just `/dev/sdx`. It has worked for me (not with Ubuntu, though). Beware that this will destroy any data previously on the flashdrive.

Answer (score 6):

There are extensive [instructions on installing Ubuntu from a USB flash drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) on their [Community Documentation site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community).  It's a little more complicated than just `dd`ing the ISO to the drive.

Answer (score 5):

There is also [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) which is a gui interface that manage the download, mounting, formating etc. It can run on windows, linux and mac. If you prefer the command line interface, I think that dd should be sufficient, you can read about this at [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Putting_installation_media_on_a_USB_key) (which point to unetbootin as an option).

Note that Ubuntu 11.04 does not work with u3 filesystem.